# angularJS interceptor: access parent controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app i have different manipulations with http request's, for example:

```
      $scope.getArticle = function(id) {
        $http.get('/app/' + id, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          })
          .success(function(response) {

          })
          .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          });
      };

      $scope.displayAlert = function (message) {
        var modalHtml = '<div class="modal-header"><h3>Warning</h3></div>';
        modalHtml += '<div class="modal-body"><strong>' + message + '</strong></div>';
        modalHtml += '<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn-md btn-green pull-right" ng-click="$dismiss()">OK</button></div>';
        $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
          template: modalHtml,
          size: 'sm',
          backdrop: 'static',
          keyboard: false
        });
        $timeout(function () {
          $scope.modalInstance.close('closing');
        }, 5000);
      };
```

and i have written such interceptor:

```
var responseError = function (rejection) {
        var rootScope = rootScope || $injector.get('$rootScope');
        console.log(rootScope.displayAlert('123'));        
        ***
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    };
```

but how could i in this interceptor when i have error call `$scope.displayAlert()` method?

sure i could do it so:

```
$scope.getArticle = function(id) {
            $http.get('/app/' + id, {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
              })
              .success(function(response) {

              })
              .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {                
                $scope.displayAlert('error');
              });
          };
```

but this is bad idea... how to be?

Comment: "but something is wrong..." what is wrong/not working?

Comment: before posting -1 write what is wrong?

Comment: @Claies how to use it here?

Comment: You need separation of concerns here. `displayAlert` looks like a generic error modal so it should not be a method specific to a particular controller - it should live in its own service (or within the interceptor)

Comment: @user2943490 no) some style is different to each controller
and if generic? how to code then?

Comment: as already said... separate `$scope.displayAlert` and `'error-message'`. dont keep displayAlert on score, create a generic factory, and then create a message object with `{type, message}`, have message to be displayed injected into that factory in some array and then display it in interceptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$rootScope` along with `$broadcast` and `$on` as an event bus to communicate between components.  Note that this may have performance impact, so you should take care when employing these methods.

in your service:

```
var responseError = function (rejection) {
    var rootScope = rootScope || $injector.get('$rootScope');
    ....
    $rootScope.$broadcast('responseError',{
        message: 'Rejection Reason' });
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.$on('responseError', function(event, data){
    $scope.displayAlert(data.message); });
```